# Prodecural ring texture

Tags: texturing, node-editor, procedural

iam trying to make a procedural ring texture animation, i have managed to make the ring texture but the animation is not infinite. I use the mapping scale values but the textures just scales. Do you have any idea for different set up?

Here is an image of my node set up:

[image]

Comment: why 'modulo'? That only produces a repetition... Do you have any image of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes. You can see the effect here:http://paperjs.org/examples/radial-rainbows/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you answer in the comments, here's a simple setup:
[image]
The square root of the dot product is the distance to the center (in this case, the distance to an empty object).
Adding some value to it before the module operation will just make the colors to cycle.

Scaling the rings loop is also possible by multiplying the distance with some other value, before the add node. Values less than 1 will produce wider rings, and values bigger than 1, thinner rings.

Comment: It works, thanks a lot, a small question, how i make it also work for negative values?

Comment: plug a math-Absolute node between the value and the add node.

Comment: I tried it, it just stops and goes from the other side, but i will find it thanks alot

Comment: So you want it to start from the center, and then grow into a loop? Then you must use more than just the modulo function... for example: If val<0, then fac=[1-mod(abs(val+dist), 1)], else fac=[mod((val+dist), 1)]

Comment: I was thinking about something like that.i think know I will check for meatball effect.